# Integration of Spring TransactionManager with BoneCP connection pooling

Tags: datasource, spring-transactions, bonecp

I'm using BoneCP connection pooling mechanism and I want to manage my transactions using support of the Spring framework. I found an example about [Spring Transaction Management](http://book.javanb.com/Professional-Java-Development-with-the-Spring-Framework/BBL0055.html) and I tried to apply this example. I got a DataSource instance from my connection pool and give this data source to created DataSourceTransactionManager as below.

```
DataSource dataSource = new BoneCPDataSource(getConnectionPool().getConfig());
DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager();
transactionManager.setDataSource(dataSource);
```

But when I test it, I saw that the transaction manager has written the data to the store before commit operation.

Can it be related with creating a new data source before transaction manager is created? or do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of the problem. I was using [SDB RDF storage component](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/sdb/index.html). It is related with the implementation of the SDB's add triple method. I found that it directly calls the commit method of the current SQL connection. There is no problem about integrating DataSourceTransactionManager with BoneCP connection pool.